# Mysql Query for a Forum categories/topics

Tags: mysql

i am trying to code a forum website where i want to show in the homepage all the categories and, for each category, the last topic if it exists(if it doesn't exist i put a button that says "create a topic").
The problem is that i am pretty new to the sql world and i can't figure out the query that i need.

so my tables are:
[Category table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoOiz.png)

and : [Topics table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaoYC.png)

so i need a table like this: [Result table needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yigIO.png)

columns that connect the two tables are cat_id in Categories, and topic_cat in Topics.

i tried this query:

> select cat_name,topic_cat, max(topic_date) AS data  from topics group by topic_cat

but i don't know how to continue.

where for each category i join only the latest topic(topic_date) and where the topic doesn't exist, fiels are null.

Thanks in advance.

(sorry for my bad english :/)

Comment: Hello Alessandro. Your english is pretty good. But please provide some code for what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is no link between the category and topic tables.
You need to set a foreign key :
E.g catergory_id in the topic table or a topic_id in the category table
depending on what table should hold the relation

Or this could be a join table...

You should check some tutorial like this one to understand this : http://www.sql-join.com/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, actually the columns that connect the two tables are cat_id in Categories, and topic_cat in Topics. I didn't specify it, sorry.

Comment: Try something like this:
`select * from category c
left join topics t on c.cat_id = t.topic_cat AND t.post_date = (SELECT MAX(post_date) FROM topics WHERE topic_cat = t.topic_cat)`    
Left join is what you shoud use if you want all the records from a table (category) even if they have no corresponding entries in the related table (topics)

Comment: Thanks alot man, works like a charm, that's exactly what i wanted!